# identity / zero for spray validations

Tags: scala, functional-programming, spray

I would like  to `fold` over spray validations.

But I do not know how to get the `neutral element` or `identity` for `Directive`.

What I want to do is

```
      def validateMap(data: Map[KeyType, Int]): Directive0 =
        data foldLeft (Directive.identity) { case (acc, (key,limit)) => 
        acc & validate(limit <= 10 && limit >= 0 , s"limit for $key has to be in range of 0..10")
    }
```

Is there a identity/neutral Element defined for Directive in Spray?
How can I get it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`pass`" is the identity Directive:

- http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.3/spray-routing/basic-directives/pass/
- https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/directives/BasicDirectives.scala#L68

> How can I get it ?

The spray docs are quite good, but looking through their source code is generally more effective. You could have found this using a grep like the following in a [spray checkout](https://github.com/spray/spray):

```
$ grep --include='*.scala' -i Directive -R * | egrep -i 'noop|empty|identity'
spray-routing/src/main/scala/spray/routing/directives/BasicDirectives.scala:  def noop: Directive0 = Directive.Empty
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot.